# Minimum number of steps required to visit every "special" point on a rectangular gird

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, searching

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Suppose we have the following grid configuration (or matrix) $G\in \Bbb{M}^{\{0,x,y\}}_{m\times n}$

(I.e $G$ is a matrix that have $m$ rows and $n$ colums over the alphabet $\{0,x,y\}$)
$$G=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & x & \cdots & x \\
        0 & 0 & x & \cdots & 0 \\
        x & y & 0 & \cdots & x \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & x& 0& \cdots & 0
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the **minimal** number of steps required for $y$ to visit each of the $x$'s on the grid (I.e.each of the $x$'s in the matrix) at least once where $y$ can move **left**, **right**, **up** and **down** one *cell* at a time?

(The $y$ and the $x$'s in the grid $G$ were arbitrarily placed, The $y$ and the $x$'s can be anywhere on the matrix, Also the number of the $x$'s on the matrix was arbitrary and there must be **exactly** one $y$ on the matrix).

---

I hope that there is some kind of mathematical formula (or summation) that can give the exact answer (in contrast to an algorithm).

And if there must be some use of an algorithm maybe we could find a **sufficiently** **tight lower bound** for the actual number?

Thanks for any hint or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) in the special case where the distances are given by the Manhattan norm.

Even this special case is NP-hard, so don't hope for a formula, or even an algorithm that scales well.

I found this reference, but haven't read it myself:

> A. Itai, C.H. Papadimitriou, and J. Szwarcfiter, *Hamiltonian paths in grid graphs*, SIAM Journal on Computing **11** (1982), 676-686.